# How to pass bash loop variable value to a batch file?

Tags: bash, unix

***My Bash Command:***

```
while read p; do
  ./Execute.bat 
done <sample.txt
```

***Execute.bat*** contents:

```
C:/runScript.bat $p
```

This doesn't work.

I have to pass the "echo $p" value in bash command to the execute.bat contents.

How do I this??

Comment: which `unix` runs batch-files in `C:\`? what's the platform you are running on?

Answer (score 0):

i haven't really tested this, but the following should work:

```
$ cat Execute.bat
C:/runScript.bat %1

$ while read p; do
$  ./Execute.bat $p
$ done <sample.txt
```

so you are passing the variable as an `argument` to the batch-file, and then use `%1` (in the batch-file) to expand the variable.